# What causes rviz black screen at startup?

Tags: ros, rviz

I have been running the same rviz conf for months and mostly have had no issues. But lately there is often a black screen at rviz startup and it happens seemingly randomly, without any error messages on the console. More percisely, the rviz visualization window where the map and robot TF-s are supposed to appear, just black color window appears and nothing else. The left and right rviz menus are present and look correct. At first it looked like just the map does not load but after trying with several different maps, it does not seem to be related to any specific map file. Also the console last rows say that the map is loaded successfully:

```
>> Map loaded from data with 651 lanes
******* Map V2 Is Loaded successfully from the Behavior Selector !!
```

So far just closing everything and running it again has helped but the issue appears more and more often, approx 50% of the cases. What can be wrong? Can anyone help me to locate the problem?

I also posted the question in ROS answers forum but didn't get any feedback or answers.

ROS Melodic, Ubuntu 18.04, Nvidia GTX 2080 Super.

Answer (score 0):

```
Also the console last rows say that the map is loaded successfully
```

What map are you loading? Could you share the rviz configuration you are facing issues with? And are you sure the map is what you expect it to be?

Also, could you try to launch rviz (bare) without the map and/or any other special plugins you might be using and see if you still face issues? If you don't, there is probably a bug in the plugin/viewer or the map you are using. I suggest turning off everything and launching them one at a time to see when the issues starts and if it persists.

Comment: I am loading a vector map. The rviz conf file is 800 lines long, here is the [link to it in textbin](https://textbin.net/Q7ldkyeSRG). Yes, the map is where I expect it to be because half of the times it loads ok (and so are different map files, not just one).

Without any map I didn't manage to reproduce the problem. But many different map files turning bad at the same time - unlikely maybe? As the problem sometimes appears and sometimes not, reproducing it without a map file may take a while but your hint to the plugin/viewer is the first suggestion I have had so thx, I will try.

Comment: follow up to that would be on the size of the map. How large is your map? Could you try to load a smaller map and see if the issue persists?

Comment: If a large map size is what to suspect, then yes, will try to reproduce with a smaller map and if it does not happen, will confirm it here soon. Thx.

Comment: Knowing nothing at all about rviz or its maps, I'd guess:,**race condition**?